# Error launching application after new start screen

Tags: iphone, ios

I added a new starting screen to my app and it doesn't work anymore. It added the header, the .m and the .xib file.

First, the error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'

This is the controller (I didn't change anything):

```
#import "StartViewController.h"

@interface StartViewController ()

@end

@implementation StartViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}



@end
```

This is the launching code in AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[StartViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StartViewController" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        //self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navController;


    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    //    [self.window addSubview:navController.view];

    return YES;
}
```

The .xib is called StartViewController.xib and only has a few label and button. Not any connections yet. I tried removing everything and the same error happened.

I went in with the debugger and it goes in the constructor of the new controller, and also the viewdidload method. The exception is thrown at the `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];` line in the delegate.

If I just change the line attaching the new controller to the old one `self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];` the app works again.

What is it? It must be something very basic but I can't find it.

Comment: Looks like something related to the memory management. Are you using ARC?

Comment: If I just change the line attaching the new controller to the old one `self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];` the app works again.

Comment: StartViewController nib file is present in the Xcode and are you sure it is not corrupt?

Comment: StartViewController.xib is in the project's directory (copy pasted the name) and I can open it normally in the designer.

Comment: Although at the beginning the files were added outside of the folder.  I moved them in the folder. Could that be the problem? I'll add them again.

Comment: Nah still the same... also cleaned project. And the new files are completly untouched, so it can't be the content. :(

Comment: Is your app universal? Or is it only for iPhone?

Comment: It's for iPhone and iPad, but for now I added only the .xib for iPhone.